# SQLite database in Windows Phone 8 multithreaded app

Tags: multithreading, sqlite, windows-phone-8

I was wondering if anyone had any good examples on how to use a SQLite database in a Windows Phone 8 application.  Most of the examples that I have seen are very basic and just show how to query or insert objects from a single table.

I would really like to know the best way to handle Object-Relation mappings and how to handle transactions in multi-threaded applications.  In iOS, they have CoreData which seems a pretty powerful way to handle all of this.  Is there anything even close for WP8?

Thanks

Comment: What did you end up using? SQLite-net async works okay for me except for Progress callbacks

Comment: Yes, I ended up just using sqlite.net.  I ended up using Async connection to start a transaction or to get a connection for reading.  I made all of my Read / Write calls use the sync connection.

Answer (score 0):

You have SQLite-net which is a tiny orm for winrt and wp8 https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net

You also have sqlite-winrt which is more complex but allow you to create your SQL queries. and custom Object mapping http://sqlwinrt.codeplex.com/

Comment: I have mostly been using the SQLite-net in my code.  I previously did not see the part about the transaction blocks.  One thing though, they don't really give any guidance on when to use the Async version vs the Synchronous version.  Are there any guidelines you know of?